# openpyxl - max_column gives wrong number of columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have made some changes to a excel file, earlier the `max_column` was giving the correct count of number of columns ( which is `67` in my file) but now after the edit in excel file it returns `1024`. The edits were nothing spectacular just changed some entries in existing data, no new columns were added.

Any common typo or mistake I could have made?

Comment: From https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/278/get_highest_row-column-are-unreliable  "2.2 allows you to call ws.calculate_dimension(force=True) in read-only mode. This will force openpyxl to go through all the cells in a sheet to find the max row and column values."

Comment: Just to add to that, reading that thread it seems that different editors save `max_columns` value different ways, so it can't be relied on to figure out the columns that have data in them. (Hence using `calculate_dimension` instead)

Comment: thank you that was helpful, additionally I noticed it is an excel thing if you scroll to right a lot then those blank columns become visible. I deleted all those blank columns and then saved and closed the file. And on reopening then the number of visible columns were back to 67 and then openpyxl read it correctly.